# Downscaling 4K iPhone video to 1080

Tags: ffmpeg, video, iphone

I am trying to downscale a huge 4K video taken with an iPhone 14 so that I can further process it with Powerdirector's mobile app for Android. I spent hours fiddling with both Handbrake and ffmpeg converting the source video, but the result was always too jerky, especially when the camera was moving, as if the number of frames per second was too low. Is there maybe a special codec that I need?

Here are the characteristics of the source video: MPEG-4, 26.3 Mb/s variable, 32.587 FPS, AVC High 5.2, 3840x2160, YUV, BT.709.

Apparently, Powerdirector works best with MPEG-2, and 1080 should be sufficient for my purpose. Can anyone help me find the correct command line for doing that conversion with ffmpeg? Since the video is almost an hour long, I would like to run the command for the first 30 seconds of the video only and then check the result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check after 30 seconds:

`ffmpeg -i [inputfile] -t 30 -c:v mpeg2video -crf 22 -c:a mp3 -vf scale=1920:1020 [outfile].mpg`

To encode the whole file:

`ffmpeg -i [inputfile] -c:v mpeg2video -crf 22 -c:a mp3 -vf scale=1920:1020 [outfile].mpg`

---

### Notes

Since your original video was in 4K, it was likely encoded in HEVC. Going from HEVC to mpeg2 is a major quality loss as HEVC as 4x more efficient than mpeg2

Comment: You are losing a lot of information when downgrading video quality. That is probably the reason for the loss of quality. The only real solution would be to video editing software with filters that can enhance the subjective appearance. ffmpeg may have settings that could help but I am not familiar with them if they exist.

Comment: thanks! VLC is playing the file but Powerdirector doesn't recognize it. I will try to find what's a more compatible format.

Comment: @moabit21, sorry, I forgot to incorporate the resolution change you wanted to make. I only changed the format. I have corrected it in the answer.

Comment: You might try `ffmpeg -i [inputfile] -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -c:a mp3 -vf scale=1920:1080 [outfile].mp4